# show or hide any forms by clicking a button using javascript in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

How to display the form when I click on Gridview button?

Basically I want to populate one form which includes the drop down and submit button in it.

By clicking on button I want to populate the form in popup box.

```
'panel' => [
        'type' => 'info',
        'after' => Html::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Allocate', [ 'id' => 'modalButton', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'),
        'showFooter' => false,
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919282/modal-pop-up-in-grid-view-in-yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used following code and resolved my issue.

```
 $this->registerJs("$(function() {
       $('#popupModal').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#modal').modal('show').find('.modal-content')
         .load($(this).attr('href'));
       });
    });");
```