# Why GridView Filters does not work when in modal bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

I have used modal bootstrap to view the GridView and when i used the filters and press the enter, it didn't work and it effect to parent window pressing submit/save button. Why?

This is my jquery function

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {

   $('#BtnModalPriceList').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
   });

});
```

and this is my modal bootstrap in parent form

```
<?= Html::button('Price List', [
    'value' => Url::to('../pricelist/list'), 
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
    'id'    => 'BtnModalPriceList'
]) ?>

<?php 
    Modal::begin([
            'header' => 'Price List',
            'id' => 'modal',
            'size' => 'modal-md',                        
        ]);

    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

    Modal::end();
?>
```

In action list, my code as usual

```
<?php
    $gridColumns = [  
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => ['onclick' => 'js:selectItem(this.value, this.checked)']],  
        [
            'attribute' => 'price', 
            'format' => ['decimal', 0],
        ],
        'date',
        [
            'attribute' => 'agen_id',
            'value' => 'agen.agen_name'
        ],        
        'remark_1:ntext',
        'remark_2:ntext',

    ] ?>
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?> 
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'kv-grid-pricelist',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
        'columns'=>$gridColumns,        
    ]);
    ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are loading Pjax through ajax (as funny as it sounds). You need to assign an id to it. All widgets loaded through ajax need to have user defined id so Yii can differentiate them from already loaded widgets.

```
<?php
$gridColumns = [  
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => ['onclick' => 'js:selectItem(this.value, this.checked)']],  
    [
        'attribute' => 'price', 
        'format' => ['decimal', 0],
    ],
    'date',
    [
        'attribute' => 'agen_id',
        'value' => 'agen.agen_name'
    ],        
    'remark_1:ntext',
    'remark_2:ntext',

] ?>
<?php Pjax::begin([
    //add some id here
    'id' => 'your-custom-id'
]); ?> 
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'kv-grid-pricelist',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
    'columns'=>$gridColumns,        
]);
?>
```

Comment: And also put your modal outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it works. Thanks to member of Yii PHP framework community in facebook.
The answer is
1. Put the modal outside of the active form.
2. Using Pjax by giving the id such as `<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'some-id']); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Pjax::begin(['id' => 'stav_id', **'timeout' => false**]);

Answer (score -1):

add : `use yii\bootstrap\Modal;`

you should  read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358398/how-to-implement-yii2-modal-dialog-on-gridview-view-and-update-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919282/modal-pop-up-in-grid-view-in-yii2)

Comment: I have already do that can the modal show up, but i cannot filter it.